# Show current week with current date as initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show the current week with the current date as initial value.

For example lets take tomorrow's date, `11/2/20`. Anyhow I want to get `Monday`, `11/2/20` and the date of the first day of the week which would be `10/2/20`.

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I tried to edit the question, so others would have a somewhat useful example. If this resulted in a wrong representation of your problem, please edit your question and fix what needs to be fixed.